# Lebesgue measure of a bounded set

Tags: lebesgue-measure

This seems trivial but how would you prove that an open and bounded set, G, has finite lebesgue measure.

Comment: It's contained in a large enough hypercube.

Answer (score 1):

Let Q be a hypercube large enough that your set A fits nicely inside Q. Then $\mu(A) \leq \mu (Q)$.